# How to bind a object with Guice in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I want to use a bind object in my service class with guice in dropwizard.

Consider the object

```
public class MinioData {
  private String endpoint;
public String getEndpoint() {
    return endpoint;
  }
}
```

And a service

```
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UploadResource {
private final MinioData minioData;
@Inject
public UploadResource(
    @Named("miniodata") MinioData minioData) {
  this.minioData = minioData;
}
```

How can I bind this object so that can be used in my service. For a String I could use

```
bindConstant()
.annotatedWith(Names.named("miniodata"))
.to(configuration.getMiniodata());
```

but since in this case it is a general object how would I bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing Guice module configured in your DW application, you can just bind the MinioData instance from the configuration object to the associated class:

```
binder.bind(MinioData.class).toInstance(configuration.getMiniodata());
```